# frequency selection and decomposition

Tags: time-series, modeling

I am new for time series analysis.  I have a dataset with 105216 rows from "2014-01-01 00:00:00" to 2016-12-31 23:45:00.  This data is for every 15min. 
I have converted my data into timeseries using this

```
   m2 <- ts(m1,frequency = 35072, start= c(2014))
   m3 <- decompose(m2)
```

start = 2014 ,  1

end = 2016,    35072

1) I have to forecast for every 15 min.  Is the frequency mentioned above is correct.  If not how can i modify it

2) when i decompose data data$seasonality provides me list of data(105216 rows) what I have to conclude from it.  Does my data has seasonality or not

3) when i decompose data data$trend and random provides NAvalues for 35672 out of 105216 what does it means.

Comment: Answer here is probably dependent on context, can you provide some?  What is your forecast horizon? ...

Comment: A good discipline to apply whenever you're learning a new data analysis procedure is to apply it to *familiar, tiny* datasets.  That will help you understand what the procedure is doing and you won't have to struggle with large amounts of potentially mysterious data. A good place to start would be a dataset contained in whatever resources you're studying: your textbook or perhaps an online tutorial or course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

105216 is the number of rows of your data ;

- 2014 : 365 days
- 2015 : 365 days
- 2016 : 366 days ( since 29 February)
- 24 hours each day  and 15 minutes for each hour

  (365+365+366) * 24 * 4  = 105216 data point

You can plot the data, and see the seosonality visually (if there exist some) by,

```
plot(m3)

or by using some other codes,

m3 <- stl(m2,s.window='periodic')
plot(m3)
```

When it comes to NA values. It **probably** stems from the method used in calculating the trend.( i.e, in moving average method for detrending the data, you inevitably lose some values from the start and end of your data.)